# Scrolling causing mouseleave to fire in IE

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, mouseleave

http://jsfiddle.net/bxB9C/

The mouseleave is being fired when scrolling up and down in IE only

Scroll over the yellow box in the example in IE to see the issue.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

```
$("#box").mouseenter(function(){
$("#mouse").html("mouseenter");
}).mouseleave(function(){
$("#mouse").html("mouseleave");
});

$("#box").bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(e){

var theEvent = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail*-1

e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();

if(theEvent /120 > 0) {
$("#scroll").html("Scrolling Up");
}
else{
$("#scroll").html("Scrolling Down");

}
return false;
});
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine (IE 9, also in Comp. Mode).

Comment: Im using IE10
And when scrolling down for a few seconds over the yellow box, The mouseleave is getting fired

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
$("#box").hover();
```

Comment: I set this up as a demo to show the issue. I need to use mouseenter and mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bxB9C/2/

I figured it out, although not sure if there is a better way

I put this in the scroll

```
scrollLock = true;
clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
$.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {
     scrollLock = false;
}, 250));
```

and on mouseleave check if !scrollLock before taking action